# What hooks/filters are there to alter selected terms on post save?

Tags: taxonomy, filters, hooks, terms

Very simple, where would I hook/filter to alter the users selection of terms when they save a post (Update or Add)?

I need to hook in all instances; such as when saving a post via AJAX, saving when JavaScript is disabled and a normal POST is done and when posts are saved via quick edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always `'save_post'` (or `'wp_insert_post'` immediately after this). In `$_POST['tax_input']` you will find all the terms for all taxonomies associated with the current post.

Example:

```
'tax_input' => 
  array (
    'location' => 
    array (
      0 => '0',
    ),
  ),
```

To change the terms you have to call `wp_set_post_terms( $post_ID, $tags, $taxonomy );` manually, just changing these values will not work because they are set when the actions fire.

For an existing post that is updated you can hook into `'edit_post'` and `'post_updated'`.

Parameters for all these actions are `$post_ID, $post` in this order. For `'post_updated'` there is a small change: `$post_ID, $post_after, $post_before`.