# Update post meta on bulk edit / update

Tags: publish, post-meta, bulk

I have a small problem with a code that works most of the time. I just discovered it cannot be used when I bulk edit custom post type. 
If I'm on individual post page and hit publish, the custom post type gets published and the user meta gets updated.

If I use the bulk edit to publish many posts at once, the user meta is not updated.

```
    function sa_ads_count() {
        global $wpdb, $post;
        $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $author = $authordata->ID;
        // get initial count
        $single = true;
        $ads_count = get_user_meta( $author, 'ads_count', $single );
        if ( strlen( $ads_count ) > 0 ) {
            $ads_count = intval( $ads_count ); // make sure it's a number
            $ads_count++; // increment by one
        } else {
            // meta isn't set, so we'll create it
            $rows = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_status, COUNT(ID) as count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = %d AND post_type = 'post_type' GROUP BY post_status", $author ) );

$stats = array();
foreach ( $rows as $row )
    $stats[ $row->post_status ] = $row->count;
            $ads_count = isset($stats['publish']) ? $stats['publish'] : 0;
        }

        update_user_meta( $author, 'ads_count', $ads_count );
    }

add_action( 'pending_to_publish', 'sa_ads_count' );
```

Any idea what is wrong here? Is it a WordPress limitation or this can be solved?
The thing is, I need this hook as I only want to count and store for every user, the number of posts that I approve and publish.

Later on, I want to change new post status directly to publish based on the number of posts the user has approved. This I already achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the $post parameter:

```
add_action( 'pending_to_publish', 'sa_ads_count' );

function sa_ads_count( $post )
{
    // use the $post variable here, not the missing global.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot toscho for opening my eyes. I got it to work with this final code:

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'sa_ads_count', 10, 3 );
    function sa_ads_count( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status == 'pending' ) {
        // the post has been approved, do stuff ...
}

Comment: @ovidiubica See my update, it is even easier. For more see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56861/73).

Comment: Too bad I can't vote for now, this is even better, I can't believe how easy this was. Little details make big difference.
Thanks a lot Thomas.

Comment: One more question, I was hoping to only count and store pending_to_publish actions but it seems this also counts new_to_publish actions.
Could this be due to the fact that users are "contributors" instead of "authors" ?

Comment: Hm, that shouldn’t happen. I think it worth a new question.

Comment: Never mind Thomas, I just found out that the theme framework sets initial post status to pending before my function is triggered.

Comment: @ovidiubica Which framework is it? This is a serious bug.

Comment: Classipress @ Appthemes, don't worry, that's how it supposed to work because posts are sent from the front-end. I set initial post status to draft and things work fine but unfortunately, I can't change this behavior without touching the framework.