# Run a function when a custom post is update?

Tags: posts, actions, advanced-custom-fields, wp-update-post

There is a custom post type. Each post has a repeater field. When a post is updated, I need to get a value from the repeater field and insert it into a custom table in the WordPress database. To do that I want to run a function when a post is updated. I have tested three 3 hooks for that. I tested `post_updated`, `save_post` and `wp_insert_post`. Neither of those is working. Here is my code:

For `wp_insert_post`:

```
function insert_values( $post_id, $post ) {
print_r($post);
if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
    if( $post->post_date != $post->post_modified ){
        echo "Post is updated";         
    }
    else {
        echo "Post is created";     
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'insert_values', 10, 2 );
```

For `post_updated` :

```
function check_values($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){
    echo '<b>Post ID:</b><br />';
    var_dump($post_ID);

    echo '<b>Post Object AFTER update:</b><br />';
    var_dump($post_after);

    echo '<b>Post Object BEFORE update:</b><br />';
    var_dump($post_before);
 }
 add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 );
```

For `save_post`:

```
function test_save_hook( $post_id, $post, $update ){
    $updated = ($update) ? "updated" : "saved";
    echo "Post type " . $post->post_type . " was " . $updated;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'test_save_hook', 10, 3 );
```

Those 3 hooks are not working. It only works when a post is created.

Comment: Did you see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56779/check-if-post-is-being-published-for-the-first-time-or-is-an-already-published?

Comment: Also echo'ing out won't work in REST API endpoints so the block editor and any other API based code will be broken with invalid JSON responses

Comment: @fuxia It's not working.

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes. I got that. If I remove echo then also it's not working.

Comment: @Sabbir33 What does "not working" mean? I know that code works, maybe you're registering your callbacks too late? We need some debug information.

Comment: @fuxia There is a custom post type. Each post has a repeater field. When a post is updated, I need to get a value from the repeater field and insert it into a custom table in the WordPress database. But it's not working. I checked the hook. Doesn't work

Comment: WordPress has no "repeater fields". That seems to come from a plugin (ACF?). Their support is probably able to help better.

Comment: @fuxia Yes. I am using ACF.

Comment: ACF has a support forum, you are better to ask there - https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/topics/